# Most up-to-date version of the java "Clearthought" TableLayout project

Tags: java, swing, awt, tablelayout

What is the status of the java "Clearthought" TableLayout project?

is it still being maintained?

what is its most up-to-date website?

old page:
http://www.clearthought.info/sun/products/jfc/tsc/articles/tablelayout/

not working:
https://tablelayout.dev.java.net/

maven repository with 2005 version:
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/tablelayout/TableLayout/20050920

any other more up-to-date page?

Answer (score 8):

It seems that the author abandoned the project. So I decided to bring it back to life: change the build system from ant to maven, split the project into core code and examples, etc.

Maven coordinates of the latest version:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>info.clearthought</groupId>
  <artifactId>table-layout</artifactId>
  <version>4.2</version>
</dependency>
```

This release is completely identical to the last old release in Maven Central with exception of 2 bugfixes.

You can [check this](https://github.com/nerro/table-layout) for more information. Feel free to contribute or improve